# Android phone: suddenly unable to connect to wifi

Tags: wi-fi

I'm having trouble connecting to a wifi network on my android phone.

I was connecting just fine for the last few months, but today it just stopped connecting.

It's not airplane more, and I haven't run any updates.

I tried "forgetting the network" and reconnecting again, but it keeps saying "Couldn't connect to network".

Have I been blocked? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Did you turn Airplane Mode ON?  Have you tried forgetting the network, then turning the phone Off (Power Off)?  Have you tried updating the phone?

Comment: @John Nope (Edited the question to include the details)

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? This just happened to me. Suddenly I could not connect to my WiFi. It happened right after I tried to configure a Chromecast gen 1 (which I couldn't connect to either).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me (LG V30S, Android 9) was to go to Settings -> General -> Restart & reset -> Reset network settings (the wording may be different since I translated from Swedish: Inställningar -> Omstart och återställ -> Återställ nätverksinställningar).